# AngularJS Material Design required attribute

Tags: angularjs, material-design

How can I set a **required** attribute for generated text input from this tag ?

```
<md-text-float id="input-name" label="name" ng-model="loginForm.name"></md-text-float>
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no way to directly set the required attribute. The directive does not support this (see: https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/textField/textField.js)...

Comment: @fynn I find a way to set required attribute: `link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      element.find('input').eq(0).attr('required', 'true');
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until this feature is still in progress https://github.com/angular/material/issues/372 
just need to add attribute using `link` function inside directive

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) { 
    element.find('input').eq(0).attr('required', 'true'); 
}
```

It works pretty good!